# Connecting to Parity running on AWS using websocket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, websocket, web3js, parity

I am running a parity node on "AWS EC2" instance. I need to connect to this parity node remotely using web-socket provider at port 8546. But I am not able to connect to it remotely, though it is working fine when I run the script within the ec2 instance.

I have already defined the inbound tcp rule for port 8546.

```
Custom TCP Rule
TCP
8546
IP/32
```

Is it possible to connect to websocket port from outside the ec2 machine?
Is there anything special I need to do in order access the web-socket port outside of the instance?

Answer (score 2):

In your config, specifically the `[websockets]` section, you'll need to specify the interface, hosts, and origins that are allowed to communicate with Parity.

By default, parity only listens on the local interface, and both "hosts" and "origin" are set to none, so only pages/apps hosted on your local device have access to your node.

I would use the websocket section here: https://paritytech.github.io/parity-config-generator/  for reference.